# Bootstrap 4 - how to align one button on the left side and remaining elements on the right side?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I need to align the B1 button on the left side and the remaining elements on the right side.

Here is my code (I'm using Bootstrap 4.1):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="modal-footer">
  <div class="clearfix">
    <button type="button" id="b1" class="btn btn-primary float-left">B1 ACTION</button>
    <div class="float-right">
      <button type="button" id="b2" class="btn btn-primary">B2 ACTION faltas</button>
      <a href="" id="b3" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">B3 ACTION</a>
      <button type="button" id="b4" class="btn btn-primary btn-danger">B4 ATION</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, the code is not working. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: try removing class ```clearfix```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the buttons inside `.modal-footer` which is using `flex-box` you can add the class `justify-content-between` beside `modal-footer`.

Now you don't have to use `clearfix` and `float`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
    <button type="button" id="b1" class="btn btn-primary float-left">B1 ACTION</button>
    <div>
        <button type="button" id="b2" class="btn btn-primary">B2 ACTION faltas</button>
        <a href="" id="b3" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">B3 ACTION</a>
        <button type="button" id="b4" class="btn btn-primary btn-danger">B4 ATION</button>
    </div>
</div>
```